# db2 data load runs slowly unless test data applied

Tags: db2, database-performance

I have a database build and a reference data build which are loaded onto my computer.  When I try to load the transaction data from a file to the database via staging tables and stored procedures it takes 20 minutes to load 10,000 records.

If I load the database build, reference data build and also my test data then loading the transaction data via the same process takes between 40-50 seconds.

I am trying to find out what causes the process to speed up when test data is added and have considered that it could be that the database may have worked out the best route to inserting the transaction data by loading the test data first, but I wouldn't expect it to be this big a difference in time.

Can anyone recommend what I could do to identity the problem or have any ideas to what it could be?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The integrity is ok? What is the time of each 4 steps in the load process?

Comment: With that level of detail, it could be anything. You need to describe what is your DB2 version and platform, what do you mean by "database build", "data build", how exactly you perform the load, what do the stored procedures do etc. Otherwise this question is a good candidate for closing.